# Limiting distribution of $Z_n = \frac{1}{n}X + (1-\frac{1}{n})Y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given $X$ and $Y$ random variables, I want to find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} F_{Z_n}(z)$, where $Z_n = \frac{1}{n}X + (1-\frac{1}{n})Y$.

I don't have any information about the distribution of $X$ and $Y$, so I am not sure how can I find the limit of the distribution of the variables $Z_n$. Any suggestions on how to proceed? I couldn't find any similar examples.

Comment: $Z_n\to Y$ pointwise, thus in distribution.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about that property.